# How to prevent a user from pushing to it's remote branch if it's branch not update to date with master

Tags: git

Could any one help I used git on local server.
I create a branch for every developer in a team. All developers make push to it's remote  branch, then I make merge and pushing it to master.

I have only one a problem, any developer can push to it's remote branch without make pull from master.

How I can solve this problem ,to make a developer must make pull from master before make push to it's remote branch? Is git-hock appropriate?

Comment: I would question whether you actually want to do this. It might make sense to make sure the branches are up to date with `master` before merging them into `master` (e.g. you could only allow --ff-only merges). But it doesn't make (as much) sense to force each person's branch to be up to date with `master` just to push to their own branch. After they push their own branch it might be out of date again a few minutes later...

Answer (score 0):

This depends how you handle the merge.

The problem is you can push something on top of master and someone else update master. So not an easy stuff. It is better to handle it on the master update.

You can set up the policy on your git hub server.
For example on gitlab you can select:

> Merge commit with semi-linear history
> Every merge creates a merge commit.
> Fast-forward merges only.
> When there is a merge conflict, the user is given the option to rebase.

Or you can add local rules if dev should update master and push it

```
git config --add branch.master.mergeoptions --ff-only
```

And on server side block for non fast forward push on master branch.

Comment: I make windows permissions for file that contains header of every branch at --bare repository , so no one can make push to a master, because they didn't have permission to modify the master file.
I want to make conditions , if remote branch of developer up to date with master then the developer can make push to its branch else (make pull from master then make push for your remote branch).